# Android Studio Set font family on Textview

Tags: android

I try to design view for my app, but cant change font family for text view.
Preview in android studio was change but if run on emulator font not the same with the preview

[Emulatorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFqG.png)

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmcJV.png)

in xml, :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textwelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearbg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/galada"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

what i missed ?

Comment: what is name of font?

Comment: galada.ttf from google, i try to make one again and its  work but not for this

Comment: Do you have this `galada` in your `assets` folder?

Comment: Solved, change Activity to AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the font's file (galada.ttf in your own case) in the **/res/font** folder, then use `android:fontFamily="@font/galada"` in your TextView.

OR

put the font's file in /assets/fonts folder and use this code in your java file to set its typeface.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/galada.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can download font (galada.ttf) form here: https://fonts.google.com

Set custom font from **res -> font ->** galada.ttf

If there is no font folder in resource directory there create it.

**Go to File->New->New Resource Directory Select font**

This will create a new directory, font, in your resources.

```
textView!!.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context!!, R.font.galada)
```